# Filtrar JSON a partir de una API

Tags: javascript, html, api, web

Necesito poder filtrar las películas(concretamente por el nombre) y solo mostrar las que ponga en el campo de búsqueda. No se que falla, la verdad. Miro y remiro y nada, no consigo nada.  A ver si me podéis ayudar.

Y que aun mirando alguna solución, no llego a dar con la solución de filtrar el JSON de la API the movie database api [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/introduction)

-Pongo este texto extra por que me aparece el mensaje de que tu mensaje es mayormente codigo y no explicas nada de nada, no entiendo por que debo poner tantas palabras para que no me de

Este es mi código:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <!-- Navigation-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#!">Start Bootstrap</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#!">
                            Home
                            <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#!">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#!">Services</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#!">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Page Content-->
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Heading Row-->
        <div class="row align-items-center my-5">
            <div class="col-lg-7"><img class="img-fluid rounded mb-4 mb-lg-0" src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x400" alt="..." /></div>
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <h1 class="font-weight-light">Business Name or Tagline</h1>
                <p>This is a template that is great for small businesses. It doesn't have too much fancy flare to it, but it makes a great use of the standard Bootstrap core components. Feel free to use this template for any project you want!</p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#!">Call to Action!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Call to Action-->
        <div class="card text-white bg-secondary my-5 py-4 text-center">
            <div class="card-body"><p class="text-white m-0">This call to action card is a great place to showcase some important information or display a clever tagline!</p></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Content Row-->
```

```
        <div class="container-fluid ">
            <div class="row justify-content-md-center gap-3" id="lista-peliculas">
               
            </div>
          </div>
    





        
    <!-- Footer-->
    <footer class="py-5 bg-dark">
        <div class="container"><p class="m-0 text-center text-white">Copyright &copy; Your Website 2021</p></div>
    </footer>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JS-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Core theme JS-->
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Esta desctivado el APP2 -->
    <!-- <script src="js/app2.js"></script> -->

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

</body>
```

app.js:(JavaScript)

```
// Donde se imprimeran los Peliculas en el HTML

const lista = document.querySelector("#lista-peliculas")

const lista2= document.querySelector("#resultado")
// Cargar los Peliculas cada vez que se recargue la pagina

// window.onload=function(){

// for (let i=1;i <=50;i++){
// cargarPeliculas(i);
// }
// }


window.onload=function(){

for (let i=270;i <=300;i++){
cargarPeliculas(i);
}
}



// Lista para ir recorriendo la variable numeroPeliculas e ir añadiendo 
//al mismo tiempo que ejecuta la funcion cargarPeliculas

function listaPeliculas(numeroPeliculas){



for (let i=0;i <=numeroPeliculas;i++){


cargarPeliculas(i);

}

}


// Petición Asincrona para la API
// function cargarPeliculas(id){
 function cargarPeliculas(original_title){

// fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`)
// fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}?api_key=917b1612e7ffc11c98c56196e6a33da0`)
fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${original_title}?api_key=917b1612e7ffc11c98c56196e6a33da0`)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((data)=>{



// De esta manera me salen en el HTML 10 Peliculas
lista.innerHTML += pintarPelicula(data);

});
// -------------------------------------------------


//Pintar los Peliculas


function pintarPelicula(peliculaJSON){

  // Para poner el nombre en Mayusculas = .toUpperCase()
  peliculaJSON.original_title= peliculaJSON.original_title;
  peliculaJSON.overview= peliculaJSON.overview;
  peliculaJSON.poster_path= peliculaJSON.poster_path;
  peliculaJSON.release_date= peliculaJSON.release_date;



// } 

return `





<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
<a href=""  clas="pulsame"><img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${peliculaJSON.poster_path}" class="card-img-top" alt="..."></a>

  
  
  <div class="card-body">
         <h5 class="card-title">${peliculaJSON.original_title}</h5>
         <h6>${peliculaJSON.release_date}  </h6>
         <p class="card-text">${peliculaJSON.overview}</p>
  </div>

  <div  class=" justify-content-md-center row " >
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>


` 






}

}






// FILTRAR PELICULAS


let busqueda = document.getElementById("api");
    
    function filtrarPeliculas(peliculaJSON) {
      busqueda.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
    
        // fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}?api_key=917b1612e7ffc11c98c56196e6a33da0`)
        fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=917b1612e7ffc11c98c56196e6a33da0&query=${busqueda}`)


        .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
    // alert("filtrarPeliculas")
            lista2.innerHTML += 

          `<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${peliculaJSON.poster_path}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          
          <div class="card-body">
                 <h3 class="card-title">${peliculaJSON.original_title}</h3>
                



                 
                 <p class="card-text">${peliculaJSON.overview}</p>
          </div>
        
          <div  class=" justify-content-md-center row " >
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>`

              // let element = document.getElementById('element')
              // document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data)
    
              console.log(data)
          })
          .catch(err => console.log(err))
    
    })
    }
      
    filtrarPeliculas(busqueda)
```

Saludos y gracias

Comment: La variable `busqueda` parece apuntar a un elemento, por lo que falta especificar el valor en la petición: `fetch(\`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=917b1612e7ffc11c98c56196e6a33da0&query=${busqueda.value}\`)`. Por cierto, si el sistema te pide que incluyas más texto, no se refiere a relleno, sino a una explicación más detallada del problema.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero aun así me sigue dando errores, ahora te explico. como ves en esta imagen https://ibb.co/f1DQKMf , al poner JAW me salen 20 JSON en un array, pero no se me pintan en el HTML. Las otras películas se pintan en el HTML por que recoge los JSON de la API directamente sin filtrar. ¿ Como hago ahora que coja cada uno de estos JSON en el filtrado y los pinte? Un saludo y gracias